# C - Memory Access Violation (But Why?)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I've made a little program that should read a file and print its content out (Yes, it *is* exactly 14 Bytes :)

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define FILE_SIZE 14

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char *buf[FILE_SIZE];

    fread(buf, FILE_SIZE, 1, fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < FILE_SIZE; i++) printf("%c", *buf[i]);
}
```

If I run it, a `Memory Access Violation` occurs.
I guess it's caused by `*buf[i]`, because if I remove the `*`, everything's right.
(Well, I get cryptic characters then, but that's allright, isn't it?)

Now, my question: Why does `buf[i]` work, but `*buf[i]` doesn't?

Comment: `buf` is an array of `FILE_SIZE` *pointers* to `char`. And none of these pointers are initialized to point to something. I suspect you really want `char buf[FILE_SIZE];`, without the asterisk.

Comment: [Clockwise/Spiral Rule - C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: `putc` is a nicer way to print a single character. You can just write `putc(buf[i], stdout)`. You can also write the whole string without looping by calling `printf("%s", buf)` or `puts(buf)`, as long as you null-terminate `buf`. `puts` will add a newline by default, but you'll have to specify one for `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops `buf` shouldn't be an array of pointers to character but array of character

```
char buf[FILE_SIZE];
```

and

```
printf("%c", buf[i]);
```

No crash